# Javafx: instance label not displayed

Tags: java, javafx

I am new in Javafx (and Java).

I am trying to display a label "title" to different scenes. Therefore this label in a instance variable. I create it using the method title().

The problem is that the title does not appear in my scenes. I tried to initialize it at class level, or inside the start(), or inside scene1(). Nothing works but when I create a local label inside the scene1() method.

Thanks in advance for your help.

ps: full [repo here](https://github.com/ebarrier/Snake) if needed

```
private Label title;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    title();
    scene1();
    scene2();
    [some more code...]
}

public Node title() {
    title = new Label();
    title.setText("SNAKE");
    title.setTextFill(Color.YELLOW);
    title.setFont(Font.font(STYLESHEET_MODENA, FontWeight.BOLD, 80));
    return title;
}

public Scene scene1() {
    Label lbl1scene1 = new Label("Welcome to Game !"); 
    Label lbl2scene1 = new Label("Click to start the game");
    Button btnStart = new Button("Start the game now!");
    btnStart.setOnAction(e -> {
        runGame();
    });
    VBox vbox1 = new VBox(title, lbl1scene1, lbl2scene1, btnStart);
    vbox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    vbox1.setSpacing(10);
    scene1 = new Scene(vbox1, width, height);
    return scene1;
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect it's not a good idea to have the same instance of a node multiple times in the scenegraph. Maybe some expert could confirm if this is indeed not recommended, or if it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Nodes are only allowed once in the scene graph. Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html): *"A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph. Specifically, a node must appear no more than once in all of the following: as the root node of a Scene, the children ObservableList of a Parent, or as the clip of a Node."*

Comment: Thank you. I forgot this important point. I think now I got it forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to display a label "title" to different scenes.

Please note that a node can have only a single parent.

Create multiple instances using local variables instead of a title member field.

Comment: Thank you for that reminder. I have indeed read it. Now it is clear. I will use local variables.